# wsl2 が起動しなくなった理由と解決方法が知りたい

Tags: wsl

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/install-win10 の通りにインストールし、昨日まで正常に動作していたwsl2が急に動作しなくなりました。
powershellからwslコマンドすら反応しない状況です。
調べましたが手がかりが全くなく、お知恵を頂きたいです。

現状況としては以下になります。

- 「Linux 用 Windows サブシステム」、「仮想マシンプラットフォーム」は有効になっている
- powershellからwslコマンドを実行しても全く反応がない
  オプションなしで"wsl"とだけコマンド実行しても反応なし。
  ディストリビューションだけが壊れているのかと思ったが、もっと深い部分で壊れてそうな…
- `\\wsl$` にアクセスできない

環境：
Windows10 OSビルド19042.985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
WindowsUpdateを実行したらwsl2が動作するようになりました。

参考に、WindowsUpdate後のバージョンを載せておきます
OS：21H1
OSビルド：19043.1052